# Installing the lme4a package on R 2.15.1 for Windows

Tags: r

Is it possible? If so, how? If not, what do I have to do to get lme4a to work on Windows?

I currently have installed the latest version on R-forge for Matrix and Rcpp and have the CRAN-versions of the other required packages. I got my lme4a package from [r-forge](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos/bin/windows64/contrib/2.14/).

Do I have to "downgrade" to R 2.14 to get it to work? If so, what is the easiest way to manage multiple R-installations?

Comment: Install it from the source code.

Comment: hmmm.  Why do you want lme4a?  I believe it's dominated by the development version of lme4 (on R-forge)

Comment: Thanks Ben, didn't realize the r-forge version of lme was different fromt he CRAN version and that it included profile() :) I am just trying to follow along in the book associated with the package :)

Comment: The env() function appears to be missing :( @BenBolker Would you know if any other function has replaced it?

Comment: In general the `getME` function fills the place of `env()` -- e.g. `env(fm1ML)$Lambda` could be achieved via `getME(fm1ML,"Lambda")`. I *believe* everything you need is available this way -- if not, please let me know ...